# In R: Replacing value of a data frame column by the value of another data frame when between condition is matched

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
set.seed(343)
testDF <- data.frame(Score = sample(50, size=50, replace=TRUE), number = rep(letters[1:25],2), Rev = rep(0,50))
sourceDF <- data.frame(min = c(1,10,20,30,40), max = c(9, 19, 29, 39, 50), rev = 1:5)
```

For each row of testDF where testDF$score is between sourceDF$min and sourceDF$max of sourceDF, replace the value of testDF$Rev by the corresponding sourceDF$rev.

I have it working with two for loops and a if condition but it is ... slow (my dataset has close to 1 million rows).
I tried using findInterval without success.

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What's `letter`? Also, please use `set.seed` when using `rnorm`. Finally, your example is not so good because `Score` will never be larger than `9` so it will never fall in any bucket other than the first one. I would use `sample` instead.

Comment: your example does not run. no function called 'letter'.  A faster solution might be found using which() and/or the apply family.

Comment: @TanDollars `apply` family isn't going to improve anything. `which` isn't suited very well here neither AFIK.

Comment: I think the answer will be found with 'which()'

Comment: Where would `9.5` fall on this data? It's >9, so not in group 1, but <10, so not in group 2 either. That's okay, but it raises the question of whether your `Score` data is a set of discrete integers, or a continuous measure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, see my comment on how to improve your question and make it reproducible. Second, here's a possible approach how run overlapping joins quickly using `data.table::foverlaps`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(testDF)[, Score2 := Score], Score, Score2) # create bounds and key
setkey(setDT(sourceDF), min, max) # Key by min, max
indx <- foverlaps(sourceDF, testDF, nomatch = 0L, which = TRUE) # run foverlaps
testDF[indx$yid,  Rev := sourceDF[indx$xid, rev]] # Update in place by corresponding values
```

Comment: Isn't it essentially just `findInterval(testDF$Score,c(1,10,20,30,40,50))` ?

Comment: `findInterval(testDF$Score,c(1,10,20,30,40,50),rightmost.closed=TRUE)` to be absolutely specific.

Comment: @thelatemail you have a point there. You probably should post this. My approach is more general though as it will work for several variables too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I guess I posted this example too quickly without testing it. Shame on me...
@David thanks for the pointers I'll look further into the foverlaps function (and will explore more the world of data tables).

I found a work-around that works pretty well and is fast. As I have a limited number of ranges (5 in the example) I just subset the tesdDF into 5 data frames using the filter function (dplyr library) on the variable Score.

```
testDF1 <- filter(testDF, Score>=1 & Score <=9) ## First DF
```

Then it is just a question of assigning the values of Rev in each of these data frames.

```
testDF1$Rev <- sourceDF$rev[1]
```

This ran in less than 1 sec vs 1h35mn for my old loop on 800k+ rows.